# onReceive not Triggered in some cases

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Below is my working code:

```
struct ReaderView: View {
    @State var presentingSettingsSheet = false
    @State var currentDate = Date()

private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

var body: some View {
    let filter = "Showing all stories"

    return NavigationView {
        List {
            Section(header: Text(filter).padding(.leading, -10)) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    TimeBadge(time: 20.0)

                    Text("Title")
                        .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 100)
                        .font(.title)

                    PostedBy(time: 30.0, user: "Author", currentDate: self.currentDate)
                    }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$presentingSettingsSheet, content: {
            SettingsView()
        })
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Stories"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button("Settings") {
                self.presentingSettingsSheet = true

            }
        )
    }
    .onReceive(timer) {
        print($0)
        self.currentDate = $0
    }
}}
```

But if I add onReceive after `List` Scope it does not work, it starts working if I add it after the declaration of `navigationBarItems`. So my question is why does onReceive behave differently when placed differently inside code. I am aware that the sequence of modifiers changes the final resulting UI but is it the same for `onReceive`. 
I am looking for a possible explanation for this.

I am using:
Xcode 11.5
Simulator iPhone SE (2nd generation), 13.5.

Answer (score 0):

this is NOT a solution and not an explanation, just further comment:

if you extend your timer to

```
private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .print()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

you will get

```
receive subscription: (Timer)
request unlimited
request unlimited
receive cancel
receive subscription: (Timer)
request unlimited
request unlimited
```

if you put onReceive to the List
in all other places (like Text or Navigation) you only get

```
receive subscription: (Timer)
request unlimited
request unlimited
```

so i think somehow at the list the Publisher will get cancelled and started again which might be the reason for "not working"

Comment: you are right, receive cancel gets printed. But its not limited to List.